Can you use RS-422 to transmit a clock
We would like to use RS-422 to send a clk to a remote FPGA on a CCA.  I have attached a block diagram of what we would like to do.  The FPGA on CCA 1 can use a differential pair, but the buffer attached to these pins appears to only use single ended.  We will then use a RS-422 receiver on CCA 2.  The output of this receiver will go to a clk capable pin.  The speed of the CLK should be around 10 MHz.
My Question is this possible?
SN74LXC8T245QPWRQ1 has VCCA = 3.3V and VCCB = 5V
THVD2450VDRCR      has VIO  = 3V   and VCC  = 5V


Do you mean you have two boards with the chips mentioned in the post already mounted and wish to use them, or do you mean you intend to design a system using these chips? 10MHz seems a bit fast for THVD2450.

What's this even good for? Aren't you rather looking for some means to sync input/output between various nodes on the network?

Yes, as per the topic, you can use RS-422 to transmit a clock - but your system has no RS-422 transmitter so is a separate matter.
Since the transmitting chip isn't RS-422 driver, it likely can't work within RS-422 specs. While it does have quite a strong output drive strength, it is not a bus buffer intended to drive long cabling terminated with 120 ohms.
Only the receiver is RS-422 and it works up to 50 Mbps.
So do try it but also you need to take into account that it does not work well for the reason I said and due to the two wires being driven separately with two different buffers and signals into the buffers.
Also the boards need to share ground as RS-422 is not a two wire interface, it needs two data wires and a common ground reference between transmitter and receiver to work properly.


My Question is this possible?

Of course, it will work fine. But whether the jitter will be acceptable or not depends on what you're using that clock for.

Inside the FPGA is a PLL and the ref clk goes to this PLL.  I agree the jitter might be an issue.
